# Python 2: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, string, list

I have a small problem with a list. I have a list called `l1`:

```
l1 = ['Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!', 'Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!', 'Amazon UK: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!']
```

And I want to delete `'Amazon FR: '` and `' - PRICE ALERT!'` from each string in my list:

*(Doesn't matter if it is 'Amazon FR' or 'Amazon UK'...)*

```
l1 = ['Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!', 'Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!', 'Amazon UK: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!']
l2 = []
for x in l1:
    x.remove[:10]
    x.remove[14:]
    l2.append(x)
```

But Python give me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Ok, if `'str'` object has no attribute `'remove'`, how can I delete some words or characters from the string using indexing?

Thanks

Comment: Strings are immutable. You can create a new string using a slice as in @mishic's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
l2 = [x[11:20] for x in l1]
```

That will leave symbols from 11 to 19 for each entry from `l1`.

Answer (score 1):

@mishik's answer works if you know the length of the parts. Here is another approach that searches for `:` and `-` and then cuts the string appropriately.  I will work for any length of string before the `:` and `-`.

```
>>> [i.split(':')[1].split('-')[0].strip() for i in l1]
['Huawei1', 'Huawei1', 'Huawei1']
```

Comment: What if the string that he's trying to extract can have a dash in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove characters from a string in Python because strings are immutable. You need to create a new string, in this case by using the slice operator:

```
>>> s
'Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!'
>>> s[11:-15]
'Huawei1'
```

In this case, we're returning a new string that starts with the 11th character from the beginning of the original string and ends 15 characters back from the end of the string, effectively trimming off the `'Amazon FR: '` and `' - PRICE ALERT!'`

In your fuller context, something like:

```
>>> l1 = ['Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!', 'Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!', 'Amazon UK: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!']
>>> l2 = [s[11:-15] for s in l1]
>>> l2
['Huawei1', 'Huawei1', 'Huawei1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l1 = ['Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!', 'Amazon FR: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!', 'Amazon UK: Huawei1 - PRICE ALERT!']
l2 = []
for x in l1:
    x = x[10:] #get everything after position 10
    x = x[:-14] #get everything until pos 14 
    l2.append(x)
```